# JPMS module-path and layers

Tags: java, java-module

I want to understand all details of module-path and layers in java9+ and I have two questions:

1. As I understand modules on module-path are added automatically only to boot layer
   and not added automatically to any other layers. I mean, if any child layers are created module-path will be ignored for them. Is this correct?
2. Not all modules from module-path are added to boot layer, but only main module and dependent modules. For example, if we have `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` modules on module-path and `A` is main module and uses `B`, `B` uses `C`, then `D` module won't be added to boot layer. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. Modules on module-path are not added automatically to boot layer or any customized layer. The set of modules found on the module paths together with system modules are known as observable modules. You can think of observable modules as a set of all the modules available to the module system in a specific phase, for example, compile-time, link time, and runtime, or available to a tool.
2. Only modules in the root set and modules that read by modules in the root set will be loaded to boot layer at start up. In your example, I assume A is the module that contain the main class. then A will be put at root set. While JPMS(Java Platform Module System) resolves all dependency modules of A, it will also look up B and C which should be put on module-path. JPMS will not resolve module D even if D is on the module-path because D will not be in the resolved module graph.

Comment: Could you say what is a root set?

Comment: The module root set contains modules that JPMS will use to build the module graph. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72523183/how-jpms-decide-root-modules-at-runtime#:~:text=The%20default%20root%20module%20set%20depends%20whether%20you%20your%20main%20class%20is%20located%20on%20the%20class%20path%20or%20the%20module%20path) is more details of it