# How JPMS decide root modules at runtime

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I am new to java module system. I am trying to understand how JPMS decide the root modules to build the module graph at runtime.

What I understand is that all modules in the module path will be added to the set of root modules. JPMS start build the module graph from the root module set and `add-modules` option can add more modules to the root modules set.
When build the module graph if there is a class not found in all modules then JPMS will search for it in the classpath, if it's found then this class will be add to unnamed module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default root module set depends whether you your main class is located on the class path or the module path.

In any case, the modules on the module path are not automatically added to the set of root modules, unless you explicitly specify `--add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH`.

If running from the classpath, most of the system modules are root modules. See [JEP 261](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) for more details.

If running from the modulepath, only the module of the main application (as specified by `--module` is root by default. Others may be added with `--add-modules`.

Comment: Straight and clear! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From book <<java 9 revealed: for early adoption and migration>> Chapter2:

- If the application code is compiled from the class path or the main class is run from
  the class path, the default set of root modules consists of the java.se module and all
  the non-java.* system modules such as jdk.* and javafx.*. If the java.se module
  is not present, the default set of root modules consists of all java.* and non-java.*
  modules.
- If your application consists of modules, the default set of root modules depends on
  the phase:

  - At compile-time, it consists of all modules being compiled.
  - At link time, it is empty.
  - At runtime, it contains the module that contains the main class. You use the
    --module or -m option with the java command to specify the module and its
    main class to be run.